# Restarting image loop

Tags: vb.net

So I'm doing a project for school and I have an image loop for my program with the code as follows

```
Dim Images(10) As Bitmap
Dim Pos As Integer = 0
Private Sub MainMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
'Inserting images from resources
Images(0) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM10
Images(1) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM1
Images(2) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM2
Images(3) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM3
Images(4) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM4
Images(5) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM5
Images(6) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM6
Images(7) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM7
Images(8) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM8
Images(9) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM9

'Puts the images into order
PictureBox1.Image = Images(Pos)
End Sub

Private Sub MainmenuSlideshowTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainmenuSlideshowTimer.Tick
'Starting the timer for the slideshow on main menu
MainmenuSlideshowTimer.Start()
'Setting the time between slides to 5 seconds
MainmenuSlideshowTimer.Interval = 5000
Pos = Pos + 1

If Pos < Images.Length - 1 Then

PictureBox1.Image = Images(Pos)
Else
Pos = Images.Length - 2
End If
End Sub
```

It works perfectly but the slideshow stops once it gets to the last image on the form. How would I make it so it continuously loops and restarts the slideshow from the first image once it gets to the last image. I'm not very advanced so I'm unsure.

Have a good day

Comment: Replace `Pos = Images.Length - 2` with `Pos = 0`. As a side note, try to stick to the [Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).

Comment: Another side note: You do not need `MainmenuSlideshowTimer.Start()` inside the `Tick` event handler. If you're already in `Tick`, that means that the timer is enabled. You also do not need to set the `Interval` property unless you're actually changing its value.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in vb.net Are declared `Images(UpperBound) As Type`. So, `Images(9)`.

`GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM10` looks a bit strange. Are you sure you are getting the images you expect?

You want to check if `Pos` is greater than `Images.Lenght -1` and reset to zero. Increment the `Pos` as the last line of the Tick event.

```
Dim Images(9) As Bitmap
Dim Pos As Integer
Private Sub MainMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Inserting images from resources
    Images(0) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM10
    Images(1) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM1
    Images(2) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM2
    Images(3) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM3
    Images(4) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM4
    Images(5) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM5
    Images(6) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM6
    Images(7) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM7
    Images(8) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM8
    Images(9) = GloriousGetaways.My.Resources.MM9
    MainmenuSlideshowTimer.Interval = 5000
    MainmenuSlideshowTimer.Start()
    PictureBox1.Image = Images(Pos)
End Sub

Private Sub MainmenuSlideshowTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainmenuSlideshowTimer.Tick
    If Pos > Images.Length - 1 Then
        Pos = 0
    End If
    PictureBox1.Image = Images(Pos)
    Pos += 1
End Sub
```